# SonarQube: How to increase the Cognitive Complexity Threshold in Sonar Portal?

Tags: sonarqube

Do anyone knows how to increase the cognitive complexity threshold in `Sonar Portal`? I searched in the portal but I could not find any clue on it.

Default is `15`, I want to increase it to `25`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to edit the value of the rule parameter in the appropriate profile. If you're using the Sonar way profile, you'll find that it's not editable there. In that case, you'll need to make a copy of the Sonar way profile and edit the parameter there. Then either set your new profile as the default, or explicitly assign the relevant projects to be analyzed with it.

Comment: Thanks for response, I think it can be done by setting up a new quality gate

Comment: This doesn't seem like a reasonable answer. It requires cloning and changing the entire profile to customize settings? You are unable to customize settings in the default profile?

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. It could be completed by listing all the steps. For example, it is not obvious to me how to "copy" a profile.

Comment: agree that this answer is incomplete.  How about identifying the rule parameter name, and even how to add rules to files.  Where is this profile thing? Whats the param in the ocnfig file?

Comment: There's no file. It's all in the UI.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam good, but what are the exact steps?

Answer (score 2):

As Ann said, this can't be edited directly or set via a configuration file (as I think we'd all hope). You need to copy the default Sonar Way Quality Profile to edit the rule, then use that custom profile by default.

From your Org's main page, click on the "Quality Profiles" tab and then filter by the language of your project (this will all need to be duplicated for multiple languages).

[image: Sonar Quality Profiles filtered by Go language]

Click on the triple-dot by "Sonar way", then "Copy" and give your new profile a name. Note that if you instead "Extend", you can't remove rules that are present in the parent profile.

[image: Triple-dot menu showing Copy option]

After creating your custom profile, you should be taken to its details page. In the Rules section, click the "Total: 25" link to access the active rules.

[image: Custom Quality Profile rules section]

That should take you to the "Rules" tab. Search for the Cognitive Complexity rule and edit the value. Note that if you get to the Rules tab another way, the search result may not show without "Clear All Filters" and filtering by language.

[image: Rules search results showing Cognitive Complexity rule]

Click on the search result to get to the details of the rule. At the bottom, there will be a list of the Quality Profiles that contain the rule. Click the "Change" button by your custom profile to edit the value.

[image: Sonar Quality Profiles with change option for custom one]

Set a new value in the "threshold" field. It would make sense for this to match your other linters, in our case 30 for `gocognit` (via `golangci-lint`).

[image: Sonar custom rule threshold configuration set to 30]

Finally, you need to set your new Quality Profile with your custom rule as the default. Back on the Quality Profiles tab, filter by language to find your custom profile. Click the triple-dot and "Set as Default".

[image: Sonar custom Quality Profile triple-dot with "Set as Default" option]

The "Code Smells" for all the Projects in your Org should now reflect the updated threshold.

Comment: One annoying thing: Extending the profile doesn't allow deleting rules in the parent. To do that, you need to copy the profile. But for me, Copying doesn't actually result in the Code Smells reflecting the custom rules. Or maybe I just broke Sonar by messing around so much, now the Code Smells aren't reflected by an Extension either.

Comment: Copying the profile instead of Extending ended up working better, as it gives more flexibility. If the Code Smells take a while to be updated, check again after a run is triggered by merging code.

Comment: Copying the profile instead of Extending ended up working better, as it gives more flexibility. If the Code Smells take a while to be updated, check again after a run is triggered by merging code.